reformatting an OS drive
I replaced my seagate 2.5" HDD (2TB) with a NVME drive. I cannot boot this computer using the new NVME drive while the old 2.5" drive still attached.
I wish to reformat the 2.5" HDD so I can use it for other purposes.
I am looking for ways to reformat, or at least make the 2.5" HDD non-bootable so that I can use the NVME drive as my boot drive, and then use the 2.5" drive for other purposes.

If you don't really care about the data in the 2.5" HDD.. just boot to a USB and wipe the HDD first? Or you can always disconnect the 2.5" HDD - install OS on the new NVMe, and then reconnect the 2.5" HDD afterwards (after making sure it booted off the NVMe drive) - and then wipe the 2.5" HDD after

Try checking on your BIOS settings to change the boot order. You can access this by pressing F11 or Del immediately after restarting depending on what BIOS your computer is running. I usually just run my fingers through F2 to F12 and hit Del and that usually does the trick 
Once you are in, look for a place that says boot order and see if you can first see the NVME and if so, move it to the top, save settings and restart.
You'd however need to install a new OS on the NVME after that.
